# Xcode 7.X main storyboard to Xcode 8.x

Tags: ios, xcode

how convert Xcode7.X main storyboard to xcode 8.x main Story board 
(my old project(Xode7.x) when open in xcode 8.x alignment show wrong)
have any easy way solve that

Comment: if its Xcode 8.2.1 then there is no issue of alignment I think

Comment: There will be no issues just convert it automatically it will give you an alert to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting below alert while opening main.storyboard

[image: Xcode 8]

Just choose a device you want in which your storyboard should fit in & then try to execute your code. There will be no changes, you just need to adjust frames as per the device model you have choosen & that will work perfectly.